# Generating nested lists of Ints

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I'm looking for a function:

```
def fun(init:Int,level:Int)
```

Such that:

```
fun(1,1) == List(1)
fun(1,2) == List(List(1),List(1))
```

This task is very easy in java by using a `for` iteration. How can I write it in Scala using the functional programing style?

Comment: You just completely changed your question, so I've reverted your change.  Please ask another question if you want to totally change it!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `List.fill` for this.  The first parameter list of this method has many overloads of variable length, and represents the number of elements at each level of nesting.  The second argument is the element to fill:

```
List.fill(1, 1)(1) //List(List(1))
List.fill(1, 2, 3)(4) //List(List(List(4, 4, 4), List(4, 4, 4)))
```

The full method definition you're looking for doesn't fit very well in to Scala, because the return type would be the least common super type of `List[Int]`, `List[List[Int]]`, `List[List[List[Int]]]`, etc.), which would be `Any` or `List[Any]` depending on your definition of `fun(1, 0)`.  It would look something like this:

```
def fun(init: Int, level: Int): Any = level match {
    case 0 => init
    case n => List(fun(init, level - 1))
}
```

But this really isn't recommended and would be considered unidiomatic in most Scala environments.

Comment: I am sorry, what I really implement it more complicate and I try to rephrase my task to a more general one which I failed, so I post the original question now

Answer (score 2):

You can solve it with the help of a recursive function:

```
def fun(init:Int, level:Int):List[_] = {
    if(level <= 1)
        List(init)
    else
        List.make(level, fun(init, level-1))
}
```

At every level it creates a list with the same number of elements as the level is by using the make function of the List object. The Elements you are creating are also Lists whith one element less then the current level is. The end condition of your function is when the number is smaller or equal to 1. That's the moment you simply return a list with the init value as Element.

Answer (score 0):

A type-safe approach involves the use of a tree for instance defined as follows,

```
trait Tree
case class Branch(t: List[Tree]) extends Tree
case class Leaf(i: Int) extends Tree
```

Then for example

```
val tree1 = Branch(List( Branch(List(Leaf(1),Leaf(2))), Leaf(3)))
```

where each consecutive `Branch(List())` pattern corresponds to `1` level.